# Type 'Notification' has no member 'Name' - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I'm trying to incorporate push notifications into my project, following the firebase documentation.  However, I'm getting an error that I can't get around. "Type 'Notification' has no member 'Name'". Thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        registerForPushNotifications(application)
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "relationship") { (error) in
            print("subscribed to relationship topic..")
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func registerForPushNotifications(_ application: UIApplication){
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
        
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
      print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
      let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("DEBUG: registered for notifications with device token: \(deviceToken)")
    }
   
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.banner)
    }

}
```

The pods I have installed in my project:

- pod 'Firebase/Core'
- pod 'Firebase/Functions'
- pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
- pod 'Firebase/Auth'
- pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
- pod 'Firebase/Storage'
- pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzGsF.png)

Comment: Check in your project. You have already created your own Notification class or structure. If you found this please replace name.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you also have Notification defined in your project elsewhere, I had the same issue and turns out I already had defined "Notification" elsewhere. Adding "NS" to my new definition helped separate out the issue. like this ->
`extension NSNotification.Name { static let tapBackButton = NSNotification.Name("randomName") }`

Answer (score 0):

Your own "Notification" might be conflicting with Foundation's "Notification. If you put "NS" before notifications, should solve this problem.

NSNotification.Name